# Breakpoint если программа зажралась

Tags: c#, отладка, память, breakpoint

Хочу поставить условный breakpoint, который сработает, если программа съела слишком много памяти. Попытался прописать такое в условие:

```
GC.GetTotalMemory(false) > 4000000000
```

Но получилось, что программа просто перестаёт работать - визуально похоже на какой-нибудь дедлок. Хотя, один раз из четырёх запусков получил такое:

[image: скриншот]

Как правильно сделать такой breakpoint? Или даже просто, как заставить VS остановить (но не завершить) исполнение при достижении некого объёма потребляемой памяти?

На всякий случай отмечу, что breakpoint находится внутри lock-секции.

Comment: А почему не воспользоваться традиционными способами поиска утечек?

Comment: А в какой точке стоит breakpoint? Может, это часто исполняемый код? Условия брейкпойнтов вычисляются отладчиком крайне медленно.

Comment: @VladD, да, это очень часто исполняемый кусок. По поводу традиционных способов, хотелось бы узнать каких. Дело в том, что я обрабатываю то, что производит другая программа и вполне понимаю, на что именно уходит память (буферизация её вывода, если у меня не хватает данных, чтобы сделать из него потоковый), поэтому меня интересует, в каких именно условиях я пропустил кусок данных. А дописывать код, который будет поддерживать суммарный размер буфера в словаре, не хочется...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Memory profiler? Я работал с Ants, вполне подходит. Триальная версия бесплатно. В 2015 Студии, кажется, есть встроенный.

Comment: @VladD, я знаю, в какой именно словарь я напихал данные и меня интересует его содержимое. Я не ищу неизвестную утечку памяти, я ищу баг, из-за которого, вероятно, теряется фрагмент данных, а все последующие 100 гигов отправляются в буфер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Традиционный способ с if и безусловным breakpoint'ом вполне сработал:

```
if (GC.GetTotalMemory(false) > 4000000000)
  offset = offset; // Тут breakpoint
```

PS: Но почему-то после этого программа перестала выжирать все 32 гига подкачки и стала вполне укладываться в традиционные 3. o_O

Comment: Похоже на гейзенбаг. Похоже, каждый раз, когда вызывается этот метод, GC смотрит и думает "О, может память почистить?"

Comment: @KoVadim, маловероятно...

Comment: Надо смотреть логи. В случае андроида я точно знаю, что GC пишет в лог,  когда он отработал. Я думаю, что подобное можно и с .NET провернуть. Если будет связь между вызовом этого кода и освободжением памяти - значит так оно и есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тогда похоже на гонки. `GetTotalMemory` отрабатывает достаточно медленно и изменяет тайминги кода.